# How to install puppet without having to manually hunt down dependencies?

Tags: rubygems, puppet, yum, rhel

I've noticed that puppet has a repo, which I've added :

```
ls /etc/yum.repos.d/ | grep pupp
puppetlabs.repo
```

I also have manually installed ruby gems:

```
[root@mrg41 rubygems-2.3.0]# gem --version
2.3.0
```

However, when I try to install puppet, I get dependency failures.  Note that I cant "yum install rubygems" on this system, so I had to manually install the gem library.

```
---> Package rubygem-json.x86_64 0:1.5.5-1.el6 will be installed

--> Processing Dependency: rubygems for package: rubygem-json-1.5.5-1.el6.x86_64

--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Error: Package: rubygem-json-1.5.5-1.el6.x86_64 (puppetlabs-deps)
       Requires: rubygems

You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

Also I get another funny error, which I'm not sure how to fix, or even if its a real problem:

```
** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
puppetlabs-release-6-10.noarch is a duplicate with puppetlabs-release-6-7.noarch
```

I'm assuming that there is a way to easily install puppet using a few components from the EPELs, on CentOS or RHEL , but I cant see what it is.

Comment: Why couldn't you install rubygems with yum in the first place? If you really can't do that you are going to need to create a dummy rubygems package (or possibly some other package name which `Provides: rubygems`) to get yum to believe that requirement is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

For the funny error that you have, It means there was a hung up process somewhere from the earlier yum installation that failed. When you started another one, it claims to have duplicate package.

Do a

```
 yum clean all
 package-cleanup --cleandupes
```

For Rubygems, can you do :

```
 rpm -qa | grep ruby
```

and post the output ? Then I can edit my answer. In principle, EPEL should contain ruby version that is up to date, if not you might want get it from http://rubyforge.org/projects/rubygems/

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the Rubygems tarball from https://rubygems.org/pages/download, extract it, and run `sudo ruby setup.rb` to install it. Then try to install puppet.